# Is it possible to delete a signed message request in Safe?

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe

A Safe co-signer has submitted a signed message:

[image: Safe signed messages]

However, we no longer want to sign this message. How can we remove it from the UI? I cannot see any delete button.

Answer (score 1):

for all issues relative to Safe{Wallet} you can ask directly on our dedicated support service at help.safe.global (the message icon in the bottom-right corner of the page).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We ignore unsigned messages, as it seems impossible to remove them now. We tried the API directly:

https://safe-transaction-mainnet.safe.global/

However, the endpoint to delete the message does not exist.